# C++ Project Won't Write to file After Export From xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, terminal

I am having a strange issue. I have a function (writedata) that take a string and writes it to a file. Is works fine and files are created when I build and run the program within xCode.

When I export the compiled project from xCode and just try to run the executable terminal app no file is ever written. I can see the process completes in terminal with no errors given. I even get the 'cout<<"Done. File Written!"' message but no file.

```
void writedata(string writedata, string filename){

    ofstream data(filename, ios::app);

    if (data.is_open())
    {
        data<<writedata;
 cout<<"Done. File Written!";

        data.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    data.close();
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What is file name? Is it path or only file name? Process creates files in a current directory. Do you know current directory?

Comment: The code looks correct. The problem must be in other code or how you're launching it from the terminal. Have tried saving the file with a fairly unique name and searching your drive for it to make sure it's not getting written in an unexpected location. Also if the filename starts with a period you need to do `ls -a` to see it.

Comment: @JohnTracid the path is relative like "./example.txt" so it should be written to same folder as the executable is in

Comment: When you export from Xcode you have a package. Inside this package you have your executable. Use Show Package Content and see if file there

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for the suggestion! I found the new file was being written under /Users/MYUSERNAME